# Can I switch between Gnome Desktop and Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, desktop-environments

I remember in **ubuntu jaunty** I tried to use **ubuntu net-book remix**. it worked and it looked so great, but I had no way to return to **Gnome Desktop**.
then I decided to remove **ubuntu net-book remix** but the title-bar disappear on maximized windows.

will it happen on unity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I correctly understood an old question I did, yes you will be able to do it. Just like now you're able to select NBR or Gnome session when you login, with Ubuntu 11.04 you'll be able to select a Gnome session at login. The only difference is that Unity will be selected by default.

Comment: is it possible on **maverick**?

Comment: Yes. It worked nice (switching at the gdm, unity was slow) on my laptop.